# RPG, how to slide the world (scene)

Tags: javascript, canvas, translation

Did you aver played to Pokemon or Zelda on GameBoy ? Surely yes, I'm trying to make a zelda like with canvas.
This is the link of my work : [whiteplay](http://whiteplay.fr/moi/)

As you can see, you are able to move. Actualy, when you press a key, your position is modifie (+1 or -1 etc ...) and I'm rewriting all of the map at any moves.
So we have the impression you do small blinks, it's not what i want.

What i want is the map under my character slide, with a fluid mouvement translation you know ?

I tried, translate(), rewrite all of the images that compose the world at any pixel but it's lagging.

You can se an exemple of a fluid deplacement here : [example](http://www.kesiev.com/akihabara/demo/game-tlol.html).
That's what i want.

This is my code and it might help you to understand how it works actualy :

```
window.onload = function(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.setGlobalAlpha;

var xPerso = 60;
var yPerso = 59;
var xCamera = xPerso-Math.round(nbCaseLongueur/2);
var yCamera = yPerso-Math.round(nbCaseHauteur/2);


setTimeout(function(){
    initialiserMap(0);
    ctx.drawImage(perso1, 0, 0, 17, 23, (Math.round(nbCaseLongueur/2))*32, (Math.round(nbCaseHauteur/2))*32-16, 32, 48);
}, 250);

function deplacementOk(sens){
    var retour = false;
    switch(sens){
        case 1: // HAUT
            if(map[yPerso-1][xPerso] == " ")
                return true;
            break;
        case 2: // BAS
            var bloc = map[yPerso+1][xPerso];
            if(bloc == " " || bloc == "7" || bloc == "8")
                return true;
            break;
        case 3: // DROITE
            var bloc = map[yPerso][xPerso+1];
            if(bloc == " " || bloc == "7" || bloc == "8")
                return true;
            break;
        case 4: // GAUCHE
            var bloc = map[yPerso][xPerso-1];
            if(bloc == " " || bloc == "7" || bloc == "8")
                return true;
            break;
    }
    return retour;
}

onkeydown= function(e){
    //alert(e.keyCode);
    switch(e.keyCode){
        case 38: // HAUT
        case 90: // Z
            if(deplacementOk(1)){
                yCamera--;
                yPerso--;
                initialiserMap(1);
                ctx.drawImage(perso2, 0, 0, 17, 23, (Math.round(nbCaseLongueur/2))*32, (Math.round(nbCaseHauteur/2))*32-16, 32, 48);
                if(infoAffiche == true){
                    document.getElementById('boiteAInfoYPerso').innerHTML = "Position Y = "+yPerso+"<br/>";
                }
            }
            break;
        case 40: // BAS
        case 83: // S
            if(deplacementOk(2)){
                yCamera++;
                yPerso++;
                initialiserMap(2);
                ctx.drawImage(perso1, 0, 0, 17, 23, (Math.round(nbCaseLongueur/2))*32, (Math.round(nbCaseHauteur/2))*32-16, 32, 48);
                if(infoAffiche == true){
                    document.getElementById('boiteAInfoYPerso').innerHTML = "Position Y = "+yPerso+"<br/>";
                }
            }
            break;
        case 68: // D
        case 39: // DROITE
            if(deplacementOk(3)){
                xCamera++;
                xPerso++;
                initialiserMap(3);
                ctx.drawImage(perso4, 0, 0, 17, 23, (Math.round(nbCaseLongueur/2))*32, (Math.round(nbCaseHauteur/2))*32-16, 32, 48);
                if(infoAffiche == true){
                    document.getElementById('boiteAInfoXPerso').innerHTML = "Position X = "+xPerso+"<br/>";
                }
            }
            break;
        case 37: // GAUCHE
        case 81: // Q
            if(deplacementOk(4)){
                xCamera--;
                xPerso--;
                initialiserMap(4);
                ctx.drawImage(perso3, 0, 0, 17, 23, (Math.round(nbCaseLongueur/2))*32, (Math.round(nbCaseHauteur/2))*32-16, 32, 48);
                if(infoAffiche == true){
                    document.getElementById('boiteAInfoXPerso').innerHTML = "Position X = "+xPerso+"<br/>";
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

function translationMap(a,b){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(a,b);
    ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
    ctx.restore();
}

function animate() {
    ctx.save();
    setTimeout(function() {
        animate();

        // get the current image
        // get the xy where the image will be drawn
        var img=imgs[imageIndex];
        var imgX=(canvas.width/2-img.width/2)*animPctComplete;
        var imgY=(canvas.height/2)-img.height/2;

        // set the current opacity
        ctx.globalAlpha=animPctComplete;

        // draw the image
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img,imgX,imgY);

        // increment the animationPctComplete for next frame
        animPctComplete+=.01;  //100/fps;

        // if the current animation is complete
        // reset the animation with the next image
        if(animPctComplete>=1.00){
            animPctComplete=0.00;
            imageIndex++;
            if(imageIndex>=imgs.length){imageIndex=0;}
        }

    }, 1000 / fps);
}
animate();
    
function initialiserMap(sens){
    for(var cpt=0;cpt<nbCaseHauteur;cpt++){
        for(var cpt2=0;cpt2<nbCaseLongueur;cpt2++){
            switch(map[yCamera+cpt][xCamera+cpt2]){
                case " ":
                    ctx.drawImage(herbe, 0, 0, 32, 32, cpt2*32, cpt*32, 32, 32);
                    break;
                case "#":
                    ctx.drawImage(wall1, 0, 0, 32, 32, cpt2*32, cpt*32, 32, 32);
                    break;
                case "1":
                    ctx.drawImage(arbre1, 0, 0, 32, 32, cpt2*32, cpt*32, 32, 32);
                    break;
                case "2":
                    ctx.drawImage(arbre2, 0, 0, 32, 32, cpt2*32, cpt*32, 32, 32);
                    break;
                case "3":
                    ctx.drawImage(arbre3, 0, 0, 32, 32, cpt2*32, cpt*32, 32, 32);
                    break;
                case "4":
                    ctx.drawImage(arbre4, 0, 0, 32, 32, cpt2*32, cpt*32, 32, 32);
                    break;
                case "5":
                    ctx.drawImage(arbre5, 0, 0, 32, 32, cpt2*32, cpt*32, 32, 32);
                    break;
                case "6":
                    ctx.drawImage(arbre6, 0, 0, 32, 32, cpt2*32, cpt*32, 32, 32);
                    break;
                case "7":
                    ctx.drawImage(arbre7, 0, 0, 32, 32, cpt2*32, cpt*32, 32, 32);
                    break;
                case "8":
                    ctx.drawImage(arbre8, 0, 0, 32, 32, cpt2*32, cpt*32, 32, 32);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Hope i gave you what you need to help me, trust me when i say you i tryed before ask you, and also hope i don't make mistakes or any wrong things with the stackoverflow rules.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a professional in canvas, but maybe you can try to use 2 canvas.
On the first you draw the world and on the second you draw your character.

The canvas of the world can be a little greater and wider than your stage. When you want to move your character you can try to move the whole world's canvas.

Some interesting links about this technique and somes which can be useful to you :

- [Optimize HTML5 canvas rendering with layering](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-canvashtml5layering/)
- [Improving HTML5 Canvas Performance](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/)

Good luck in your project ! :-)

Comment: Thanks to your answer, i will look at your links, i know how to move the map, but if i separate the world and the main character (they will have other character after) i will have the same problem no ? I will have to "slide" the world :/ understand ? :)